# Conditional search on js Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a optimised way to conditionally search a property in an object:

```
const testObj = {
  a: true,
  b: false
};
Object.keys(y).filter(check => testObj[check] == true);
```

answer:

> ["a"]

But I don't think, that this is a optimised way, assuming it as a larger object...

*Note:* I don't want to use array in any sense for this, so please tell me for the object only.

Comment: You can use Array.prototype.filter method

Comment: What is the condition? Currently it just returns the first key of `Object.keys()` array. You probably need `for(const key in testObj) if(<some condition with key or testObj[key]>)` return key

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry for the wrong query,I've updated my question

Comment: If you just want to check if a property exists on an object, why not using `Object.hasOwnProperty(check)`?

Comment: @adiga maybe `Object.keys(testObj).find(key => testObj[key])` or `Object.keys(testObj).find(key => validateValue(testObj[key]))`

Comment: @mati.o No, I don't want to check for the property to be exist or not, please check the updated answer

Comment: @Adarsh For mentioned usecase, its fast enough. If you have an object that might go beyond 1M keys, you might worry. However, as pointed in **adiga**'s comment, `for...in` might be a little faster. But this seems like a micro optimization. I'd suggest you to rather improve algo/ processing instead

Comment: Are you looking for *one* property or *all* properties that have a truthy value?

Comment: assuming that you want to get all keys which have a value of `true`, then this is already quite efficient. Since you'll have to look at each key once (giving O(N) total) to determine whether or not the key should be included in your resulting array or not. If you use adiga's `for...in` approach you can achieve this with N iterations rather than 2N. But in terms of scalability, this wouldn't have much of a big impact.

Comment: @adiga I can get the answer but, I will always get the first object pair that will match the condition, but in my case I want all the objects that match that particular condition

Comment: @Adarsh you can `.push()` the key into an array instead of returning

Comment: @str I'm looking for all the properties that match the particular condition